# Ignore File revision to match with IP address regex

Tags: regex, ip-address

File revision numbers are in quadruples and they are getting matched when I try to match IP addresses in a Log file. Could someone suggest a generic filter to avoid such file revision to be taken as IP address?

Here is a sample Log line:

```
importing custom report [Servers Last Week Backup Job Summary], revision [$Revision: 1.1.2.2 $123123123123] from file
```

And currently used regex:

```
(([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3}))
```

Of course, we could address the above case by a look behind. But I would appreciate if the solution touches only the quadruples.

Comment: I think it won't be possible by only touching the quadruples, as you put it. Since your revision code matches 1-1 with IP structure, you need something like @siam's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following *regex (using [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))* to avoid Revision to be taken as IP :

```
(?<!\$Revision:\s)(([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3}))
```

see [demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/4V5KRM/1)

Comment: Sorry, The question has been updated. Matching the Revision string won't be a big deal. I respect your response anyway.

Comment: @jeffrycopps I guess that's the solution you wanted that only touches the quadruples, right?